# How to remove value below a certain digits?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

Say, I have 10 phone numbers.

Each number has maximum 10 digits.

But some of them only have 4.

How to remove the number that doesn't reach to 10 digits ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=IF(LEN(B2) = 10, B2, "")
```

If sets the cell to the phone number if the length is 10, otherwise it sets the cell to blank (`""`)

[image: Screenshot of excel]

Comment: By the way, if I want to select multiple maximum value, like not only 10 but 9 as well, how do I add up in the formula ?

Comment: I set it as "equal to 10" `=IF(LEN(B2) = 10, B2, "")` but you can easily set it to "9 or longer" `=IF(LEN(B2) >= 9, B2, "")`. If this has answered your question I would appreciate it if you could mark the solution as accepted. Thanks Philong :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a VBA script. Open it up by pushing Alt+F11 and paste the code. If you want to do multiple checks, change 
    If Len(Cells(i, 1)) < 10 Then
to e.g
    If Len(Cells(i, 1)) < 10 Or Len(Cells(i, 1)) > 5 Then

Valid operators for this would be Or/And

```
Sub PhoneNoStrLen()
Dim last As Long, i As Long
last = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = last To 1 Step -1
    If Len(Cells(i, 1)) < 10 Then
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```